# Why is numpy.dtype('float64') special?

Tags: python, numpy

Can someone explain the logic behind the output of the following script?

```
import numpy
if(numpy.dtype(numpy.float64) == None):
    print "Surprise!!!!"
```

Thanks :)

Comment: It prints. What the crap?

Comment: that's the question (a good one)

Comment: `None` is special, try `np.dtype(None)` which outputs `dtype('float64')`

Comment: I don't even know what `dtype.__eq__` does. I hope someone can find the source code for that.

Comment: @user2357112: I found it--see my answer.

Comment: OK so John Zwinck answered this. Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575699/why-does-numpy-dtypenumpy-float64-evaluate-to-false for more strangeness ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to compare an arbitrary object against exactly `None` in python you need to use:

```
object is None
```

Like in this case any object may override its comparison operator to not do what you are expecting.

As for why, dtype('float64') is equivalent to None in the context of dtypes in the same way dtypes are equivalent to typestrings

```
np.dtype('i4') == 'i4'
True
```

Equality is not identity.

As for why `dtype(None) == dtype('float64')`, many functions in numpy have `dtype=None` keyword arguments. In most cases this means default dtype which is `dtype(None)`. An example is `np.zeros`. But there are exceptions, e.g. when the dtype can be inferred from the arguments, like in the case of `np.arange(10)` where the default dtype will be of integer type (`np.intp` I think).

Answer (score 9):

Looks like an unfortunate accident: someone decided that `dtype(None)` would "default" to float (though `dtype()` is an error).  Then someone else wrote `dtype.__eq__` such that it converts its second argument to a dtype before comparing.  So `dtype(float) == None` is `dtype(float) == dtype(None)` which is true.

You can see a comment in the source code here: [descriptor.c#L1217](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/dfe6c7ed74c087c0deabfd4f7a50224498840838/numpy/core/src/multiarray/descriptor.c#L1217)

> - Get typenum from an object -- None goes to NPY_DEFAULT_TYPE

And of course NPY_DEFAULT_TYPE is float (at least usually).

As for the `__eq__` operator, it's here: [descriptor.c#L3317](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/dfe6c7ed74c087c0deabfd4f7a50224498840838/numpy/core/src/multiarray/descriptor.c#L3317).  It does what I outlined:

```
if (!PyArray_DescrCheck(other)) {
    if (PyArray_DescrConverter(other, &new) == NPY_FAIL) {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

So that's a conversion from whatever is on the right-hand side of `==` to a dtype object, via the converter function mentioned before, which turns `None` into `dtype(float)`.

**Edit:** I found this pretty interesting and it seems like an accident, so I created a patch and submitted to the maintainers: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/4532 .

Comment: OK unfortunate, but makes sense. That does not explain http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575699/why-does-numpy-dtypenumpy-float64-evaluate-to-false though :)