# Why does numpy.dtype(numpy.float64) evaluate to False

Tags: python, numpy

Can someone explain the logic behind the output of the following script?

```
import numpy
if(numpy.dtype(numpy.float64):
    print "Expected"
else:
    print "Surprise!!!!"
```

Especially considering:

```
import numpy
if(object):
    print "Expected!"
else:
    print "Surprise"
```

Thanks :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is numpy.dtype('float64') special?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575050/why-is-numpy-dtypefloat64-special)

Comment: @StephenDiehl that question is about why `dtype('float64') == None`; this one is about why `bool(dtype('float64')) == False`.

Comment: I do not believe it is. "Why is numpy.dtype('float64') special?" is answered, but the answer does not apply in this case. So related: absolutely; but not a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`np.dtype` does not define `__nonzero__`, but it does define `__len__`.  As per the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html), this means when you use it in a boolean context, it will evaluate to True if `__len__` returns non-zero.  But it always returns zero, regardless of what type you pass in:

```
>>> bool(np.dtype(int))
False
>>> bool(np.dtype(float))
False
>>> bool(np.dtype(np.int8))
False
```

On the other hand, a compound data type does return nonzero, thus True:

```
>>> bool(np.dtype([('foo', int)]))
True
```

You might then ask why the "length" of a simple dtype is zero, when the length of a compound one with a single element is one.  I imagine that's something about dimensionality: an array with a simple dtype and one-dimensional size is itself one-dimensional, but an array with a compound dtype and one-dimensional size may be thought of as two-dimensional, regardless of how many elements are in the compound dtype.

Comment: Strange, especially since 0-dimensional arrays properly raise `TypeError` for `len`. I suspect these parts of the dtype API just didn't get much attention.

Comment: Thanks! That explains it. I would consider that a bug in numpy. easily fixed by defining __nonzero__ in numpy.dtype?

Comment: Your supposition about compound dtypes seems to be slightly off: `len(np.dtype([('foo', int), ('bar', int)]))` is 2. `__getitem__` also exists, and behaves as you would expect. @TroelsBlum this isn't necessarily a bug. It seems dtypes follow the sequence protocol, with simple dtypes being an empty sequence - and empty sequences *are* conventionally False.

Comment: @lvc: I know a two-element compound dtype has len==2.  That makes sense.  It also has dimension 1, conceptually.  My point is that a simple dtype has dimension 0, so a 1D array of floats is 1D, but a 1D array of `dtype([('foo', float)])` can be considered 2D.