# Creating new column using for loop returns NaN value in Python/Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, date, dataframe

I am using Python/Pandas to manipulate a data frame. I have a column 'month' (values from 1.0 to 12.0). Now I want to create another column 'quarter'. When I write -

```
for x in data['month']:
print ((x-1)//3+1)
```

I  get proper output that is quarter number (1,2,3,4 etc). [image]

But I am not being able to assign the output to the new column.

```
for x in data['month']:
data['quarter'] = ((x-1)//3 + 1)
```

This creates the quarter column with missing or 'NaN' value - [image: like this]

My question is why I am getting missing value while creating the column ?

Note: I am using python 3.6 and Anaconda 1.7.0. 'data' is the data frame I am using. Initially I had only the date which I converted to month and year using

`data['month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(data['first_approval']).month`

Interestingly this month column shows dtype: float64 . I have read [somewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575050/why-is-numpy-dtypefloat64-special) "dtype('float64') is equivalent to None" but I didn't understand that statement clearly. Any suggestion or help will be highly appreciated.

This is what I had in the beginning:[image]

This is what I am getting after running the for loop:[image]

Comment: Can u post your dataFrame sample data

Comment: Added at the bottom of the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below:

```
df['quarter'] = df['month'].apply(lambda x: ((x-1)//3 + 1))
```

Comment: It works. Haven't used lambda so far, need to check the documentation on it.

Comment: Glad to introduce you a good thing pf Python, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to get the quarter from the date would be to

```
data['quarter'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(data['date']).quarter
```

the same way as how you achieved the month information.

The below line would set the entire column to the last value achieved from the calculation. (There could have been some value which is not of a proper date format, hence the NaNs)

```
data['quarter'] = ((x-1)//3 + 1)
```

Comment: It works. Didn't think .quarter will work in the same way. Now I understand why I was getting NaN for the quarter column. Thanks for your explanation. One more question - So, if I want to use any calculation on a column to create a new one, say a for loop or if else, how do I do it ? @Rehan Azher showed a way to do it is using  lambda function. Is there any other way ?

Comment: You might have to use df.loc/iloc/at/iat. Though lambda is the preferred way unless you have large piece of calculations/code to be run.